# Kendo dropdownlist to have a link text at the bottom list item

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a kendo dropdownlist populated with dynamic array of objects.

ex.

reading from a remote source for the datasource

```
function myVM(){

var self = this;
self.myArrayValues = [
                     { Id: 0, Value: "Value1" }, 
                     { Id: 1, Value: "Value2" }, 
                     { Id: 2, Value: "Value3" }
                    ];
self.SelectedId = ko.observable();

self.OpenNewWindow = function(){
     // this function will be called when clicking the last item in the dropdown list
};

}
```

then binding it to a kendo dropdownlist like this;

```
<input id="enums" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: myArrayValues, dataTextField: 'Value', dataValueField: 'Id', value: SelectedId, optionLabel: 'Select item...'}" />

<ul>
   <li>
      Value1
   </li>
   <li>
       Value2
   </li>
   <li>
       Value3
   </li>
   <li>
       I want another item here that would be a link text to redirect to somewhere else or open a popup dialog

       Such as

       <a href="#" data-bind="click: OpenNewWindow">Open new window</a>
   <li>
</ul>
```

I hope someone could point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want  to add a link to a dropdownlist which is not a very good idea.
Instead use `onChange` event of kendo dropdown list

[Check the example here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/events)

Write you onchange function in such a way that when the last value is selected, you open a new window. Basically it acts like a link, like you want. On selection of last item, a new window opens

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I am looking for. What I want is to add another option which was not included in the original list items. In my example, I have Value1, Value2, and Value3, now I need to add a clickable link at the bottom to Create new Value. Thanks

Comment: You mean user can add more values to the dropdownlist, by clicking on link? Like an edit option?

Comment: and that link will in the dropdown or outside of the drodown below it?

Comment: yes, that's what it should be, should be in the dropdown. but i don't know if it's possible to do

Comment: @confused That's why I gave you the answer above. That's how you can achieve it. You cant add a link inside dropdown and hence you add your text at a specific index and write your onchange function; if index is for the text, then do whatever you want like allow adding new option in ddl